# Azure CDN endpoint - not able to add response header

Tags: azure, azure-cdn

I was trying to set CDN(standard CDN) endpoint rule in Rule Engine to add response header"X-Content-Type-Options". But, its not getting added.

Note: Deployed Angular app(static web site) on Azure with Azure blob storage.

[image]

Comment: How long has it been since you added the rule? It takes approximately 10 minutes for configuration changes in the Rules Engine to propagate to endpoints.

Comment: @esqew that seems to be the problem, thanks